# How to resize a win form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to C#. I just created a small C# win form application. After made it's set up file I installed it on my friend's PC and checked it. But when i opened it, most of the buttons in the right side goes out (Can't see in the screen).

I developed the application in my PC(OS: windows 7,Screen resolution 1366x768 display size smaller(100%)). And my friend's PC runs on Windows XP with Screen resolution 1024x768, display size Medium(125). How can i resolve this problem. How can made a C# win form which is compact-able to all screen size and resolutions?

Comment: You should set the `Anchor` or `Dock` properties of your controls (in e.g your buttons)

Comment: How to use it?My form contains several buttons in the right side

Comment: Using the designer (most easy way) you could set Anchor to Bottom, Right for each such button. Then resize your form to see how the buttons react, if it doesn't fit, change to different anchor positions.

Comment: Is it effcetive in case of a form??? i wish to make that  form too resizable with the screen size and resolution

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the designer and select the button. If you don't see a properties window, you can rightclick the button and select the properties option.
In the properties you will find a fild named: Anchor, this is holding the buttons on the right place when resizing a form. Go play with it and you will figure it out i think.
(I think your solution is to select the right and bottom anchor :)).

Stefan.

Comment: did anchor is available for a form?

Comment: Sorry i meaned to select the button and choose the anchor from that :). My mistake.

Comment: but its not working,its default value was Top,Left.I changed it to Bottom,Right.But no change

Answer (score -1):

try

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

It will always open the form in maximized state on any screen resolution.

Comment: This doesn't change anything to the button positions.